# Establecer hora mínima y máxima en TimePickerDialog

Tags: java, android

Como puedo establecer por ejemplo que el usuario solo pueda elegir entre las 6:00 A.M y las 6:00 PM en un `TimePickerDialog` y que las demás horas estén deshabilitadas si no están en el rango en este caso desde las 6:01 PM hasta las 5:59 A.M estarían deshabilitadas para su selección, este es mi `TimePickerDialog`

```
TimePickerDialog recogerHora = new TimePickerDialog(getContext(), (view12, hourOfDay, minute) -> {
    String horaFormateada = (hourOfDay < 10) ? CERO + hourOfDay : String.valueOf(hourOfDay);
    String minutoFormateado = (minute < 10) ? CERO + minute : String.valueOf(minute);

    String AM_PM;

    if(hourOfDay < 12) {
        AM_PM = "a.m.";
    } else {
        AM_PM = "p.m.";
    }

    horaET.setText(horaFormateada + DOS_PUNTOS + minutoFormateado + " " + AM_PM);
}, horaClock, minutoClock, false);

recogerHora.show();
```

He investigado al respecto pero no encuentro nada que me pueda ayudar, espero me puedan ayudar de antemano muchas gracias!

Comment: He estado mirando mis apuntes, pero no encuentro la manera de hacerlo con `TimePickerDialog`, borro mi respuesta para evitar confusión en un futuro, espero que te puedan ayudar.

Comment: Hola @FranCámara no te preocupes gracias de todas formas, saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para establecer hora mínima y máxima en `TimePickerDialog`, al igual que en un `DatePickerDialog` lo debes realizar en el listener que detecta el cambio en este caso `OnTimeSetListener`.

En el caso del `TimePickerDialog` las horas no se pueden deshabilitar (puedes usar como opciòn esta biblioteca [MaterialDateTimePicker](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker) pero tu puedes realizar la validaciòn.

Establece las horas minimas y maximas permitidas y las comparas con la hora seleccionada usando las funciones [after()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after-java.util.Date-) y [before()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before-java.util.Date-) .

```
        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHourOfDay, int selectedMinute) {
                        Calendar tempDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                        tempDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,selectedHourOfDay);
                        tempDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE,selectedMinute);
                        
                        SimpleDateFormat mSDF=new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy hh: mm a");

                        //Hora minima 5:59 A.M
                        Calendar dateTimeMin=Calendar.getInstance();
                        dateTimeMin.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,5);
                        dateTimeMin.set(Calendar.MINUTE,59);

                        //Hora maxima 6:01 P.M
                        Calendar dateTimeMax=Calendar.getInstance();
                        dateTimeMax.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,18);
                        dateTimeMax.set(Calendar.MINUTE,1);

                        //*Valida si la hora seleccionada es permitida.
                        if(tempDate.after(dateTimeMax) && tempDate.before(dateTimeMin)){
                            Calendar datetime=Calendar.getInstance();
                            datetime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,selectedHourOfDay);
                            datetime.set(Calendar.MINUTE,selectedMinute);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hora permitida! " + mSDF.format(tempDate.getTime()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hora no permitida! " + mSDF.format(tempDate.getTime()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }

                    }
                }, mHour, mMinute, true);
        timePickerDialog.show();
```